# GCE randomly changing disk names for additional mounted disks under /dev/disk/by-id?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I see an apparent random problem about once a month that is doing my head in.  Google appears to be changing the naming convention for additional disks (to root) and how they are presented under `/dev/disk/by-id/` at boot.

All the time the root disk is available as `/dev/disk/by-id/google-persistent-disk-0`

MOST of the time the single extra disk we mount is presented as `/dev/disk/by-id/google-persistent-disk-1`

We didn't give this name but we wrote our provisioning scripts to expect this convention.

Every now and then, on rebooting the `VM`, our startup scripts fail in executing a safe mount:

```
/usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount -m "mkfs.ext4 -F" /dev/disk/by-id/google-persistent-disk-1 /mountpoint
```

They fail because something has changed the name of the disk.  Its no longer `/dev/disk/by-id/google-persistent-disk-1`  its now  `/dev/disk/by-id/google`-{the name we gave it when we created it}

Last time I updated our startup scripts to use this new naming convention it switched back an hour later.  WTF?

Any clues appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this question is best suited for SO; perhaps [Superuser](http://superuser.com) would be more appropriate...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A naming convention beyond your control is not a stable API. You should not write your management tooling to assume this convention will never be changed -- as you can see, it's changing for reasons you have nothing to do with, and it's likely that it will change again. If you need access to the list of disks on the system, you should query it through udev, or you can consider using `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` which will not change (because the UUID is generated at filesystem creation) instead of `/dev/disk/by-id/`.

Comment: Thanks,  I did wonder if this might be the case.  The Google docs I found on this always just referred to mounting /dev/disk/by-id so I just presumed that was the best practise recommended approach for GCE.

I imagine we can get the UUID when our scripts remotely (re)provision the environment (inc disks) and then code that into the server start scripts to do a /dev/disk/by-uuid  instead.